# Apply Linux Executable on multiple argments

Tags: linux, executable

I have a linux executable "segment" that takes an image as an input inputImage.ppm, segments it into superpixels and the output is another image outputImage.pnm.

I would like to apply this executable on a whole image set that I have in a folder (400 images), how can I do that?

I have tried this:

```
    ./segment 0.8 100 100 ..pathToInFolder../image%d.ppm ..pathToOutFolder../image%d.pnm
```

Where the first three arguments (0.8,100,100) are parameters.

BTW the images are stored with names image0, image1, ...., image399

Comment: You say, *I have tried this* but haven't indicated whether that worked or not, and how it failed if it did. Did you write `segment` yourself or is it given? And if not, do you have a manual page for it so that you know what kind of arguments it can take? It's unclear from your question whether it even accepts multiple file arguments or what other kind of arguments it takes.

Comment: segment was provided to me, when I apply it on a single image, it works fine and I get the output image. But when I try to apply what I mentioned in my question, to a group of images within a folder named image0, ... image399 using the way I described above, I get the following error:


loading input image.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pnm_error'
Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in $(seq 0 399); do
     ./segment 0.8 100 100 ..pathToInFolder../image${i}.ppm ..pathToOutFolder../image${i}.pnm
done
```

Note that `${i}` instead of your `%d`. Assuming bash and standard tools, which should contain ´seq´ command.

Comment: In that case it is best to accept the answer, so that the question appears as closed, so that the best answer is displayed as first. (This is general rule, of course in this case it improves my reputation :)) And perhaps upvote comments that helped you also.

Comment: Thanks, I am pretty new here and I will start up-voting other answers as soon as I get my first 15 reputations

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to write a makefile to do this?  Is the example you give above supposed to be a makefile?

```
PARAMS := 0.8 100 100

INPUTDIR := ..pathToInFolder..
OUTPUTDIR := ..pathToOutFolder..

INPUTS := $(wildcard $(INPUTDIR)/image*.ppm)

OUTPUTS := $(patsubst $(INPUTDIR)/image%.ppm,$(OUTPUTDIR)/image%.pnm,$(INPUTS))

.PHONY: all
all: $(OUTPUTS)

$(OUTPUTDIR)/image%.pnm : $(INPUTDIR)/image%.ppm ./segment
            ./segment $(PARAMS) $< $@
```

Comment: I guess the OP just put wrong tag "makefile", as he doesn't mention any makefiles elsewhere

Comment: No not a makefile,
I have an executable that I get after I compile a C++ project (not written by me), so I get the executable "segment"
I can apply it on a single image, for example image0.ppm to get the output image0.pnm.....
I am just looking for a way I can apply it to a group of images instead, from the terminal, in a similar manner to the way I tried, which is included in my question above.

Comment: Well, one way is to write a makefile.  The one I provided will do what you want.  If you don't want to do that then you'll have to write a shell script loop.

Comment: The advantage(?) of a makefile over a shell script is that if you update just a few of the PPM files, you can re-run `make` and it will only re-convert those modified files to PNM files, so you don't have re-convert all of them as the shell for-loop would do.  But, maybe you don't modify them individually.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for file in /path/To/In/Folder/*
do
  /full/path/to/segment 0.8 100 100 $file /path/To/Out/Folder/$file.pnm
done
```

Comment: this has problem that `$file` will be `/path/To/In/Folder/file1.pnm` , so you'd need to strip the path  - using `basename` for example.